# YouTube API difference between published time and updated time of a youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

What is the difference between the published time and updated time of a youtube video obtained through the YouTube API call?

It shows difference values but shouldn't it be the same?

Meaning a person uploaded the video and updated it later by uploading another video under the same title?

Or the updated time is the time for the last comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

published time, is the time the video was uploaded to the channel.
And updated time, is the last time a change has been made on the video information. (For example, the description might have been updated.)